# Lazy load jQuery plugin doesn't work on images loaded via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, lazy-loading

I use the lazyload plugin to load images on my website and it works great but when the images are loaded via AJAX (When you click on a thumbnail to load a post) the plugin doesn't seem to work on these images. Could it be that it's because the images were not initially in the DOM?

Any idea what I could do to solve this?

Many thanks.

Plugin: https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload

```
$("body img").lazyload({ 
    effect : "fadeIn",
    failure_limit : 99999,
    threshold : 100
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
testFunc = function(str, callback) {
    // Send our params
    var data = 'some data to send';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.myurl.com',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {

    $("body img").lazyload({ 
        effect : "fadeIn",
        failure_limit : 99999,
        threshold : 100
    });


        }
    });
}
```

Put the above function after success of ajax call..Since the image  is not there event is not binding with those images.